Can I promote Premium via self-ads?
I’m working on an Android app where I don’t want to sell subscriptions directly through Google Play. Obviously, I know I can’t include external links or anything for purchasing via a third-party provider.
However, I was wondering if it would be allowed to show my own ads (banners, interstitials, etc.) by implementing AppLovin or a custom ad system to promote the Premium version of my app? Basically, I’d be using my own ads to advertise the Premium features—would this be something that Google would consider against their policies and could lead to penalties?
Thanks for your insights!
